# jQuery Chosen for woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-chosen

I am using woocommerce plugin with wordpress. I need to use jquery chosen for product variations drop down.

woocommerce already have chosen plugin in folder

```
\plugins\woocommerce\assets\js\chosen
```

how can I enable it.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('admin_print_styles', array($this, 'admin_scripts'));

public function admin_scripts() {
        global $wp_scripts;
        wp_enqueue_script('wc-enhanced-select'); // if your are using recent versions
        //wp_enqueue_script('chosen'); // if your are using some old versions
        wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_admin_styles', WC()->plugin_url() . '/assets/css/admin.css');

    }
```

And in you select box you can apply this class="wc-enhanced-select" or  class="chosen_select"  accordingly

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Chosen CSS needs include manually. WP won't do this job by default.

Here is the code to enqueue the script

```
add_action('admin_print_styles', array($this, 'admin_scripts'));
public function admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_admin_styles', WC()->plugin_url() . '/assets/css/admin.css');
}
```